# Mongo range query slow on objects inside array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection
orders

```
{
    "_id": "abcd",
    "last_modified": ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "suborders": [
        {
            "suborder_id": "1",
            "last_modified: ISODate("2016-01-02T00: 00: 00Z")
        },  {
            "suborder_id":"2",
            "last_modified: ISODate("2016-01-03T00:00:00Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

I have two indexes on this collection:
{"last_modified":1}
{"suborders.last_modified": 1}

when I use range queries on last_modified, indexes are properly used, and results are returned instantly. eg query: `db.orders.find({"last_modified":{$gt:ISODate("2016-09-15"), $lt:ISODate("2016-09-16")}});`

However, when I am querying on suborders.last_modified, the query takes too long to execute. eq query:`db.orders.find({"suborders.last_modified":{$gt:ISODate("2016-09-15"), $lt:ISODate("2016-09-16")}});`

Please help debug this.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to use [min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.min/) and [max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.max/) to set the index bounds correctly.  For how to approach debugging, read on.

A good place to start for query performance issues is to attach `.explain()` at the end of your queries.  I made a [script](https://gist.github.com/lrakai/8c240ae123e0099b0e7b96a647a8ee9c) to generate documents like yours and execute the queries you provided.

I used mongo 3.2.9 and both queries do use the created indices with this setup.  However, the second query was returning many more documents (approximately 6% of all the documents in the collection).  I suspect that is not your intention.

To see what is happening lets consider a small example in the mongo shell:

```
> db.arrayFun.insert({
    orders: [
        { last_modified: ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z") },
        { last_modified: ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
    ]
})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

then query between May and July of 2015:

```
> db.arrayFun.find({"orders.last_modified": {
    $gt: ISODate("2015-05-01T00:00:00Z"),  
    $lt: ISODate("2015-07-01T00:00:00Z")
}}, {_id: 0})
{ "orders" : [ { "last_modified" : ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z") }, { "last_modified" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z") } ] }
```

Although neither object in the array has last_modified between May and July, it found the document.  This is because it is looking for one object in the array with `last_modified` greater than May and one object with `last_modified` less than July.  These queries [cannot intersect multikey index bounds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/multikey-index-bounds/), which happens in your case.  You can see this in the `indexBounds` field of  `explain("allPlansExecution")` output, in particular one of the lower bound or upper bound `Date` will not be what you specified.  This means that a large number of documents may need to be scanned to complete the query depending on your data.

To find objects in the array that have `last_modified` between two bounds, I tried using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/).

```
db.orders.find({"suborders": {
    $elemMatch:{ 
        last_modified:{
            "$gt":ISODate("2016-09-15T00:00:00Z"), 
            "$lt":ISODate("2016-09-16T00:00:00Z")
         }
     }
}})
```

In my test this returned about 0.5% of all documents.  However, it was still running slow.  The `explain` output showed it was still not setting the index bounds correctly (only using one bound).

**What ended up working best** was to manually set the index bounds with [min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.min/) and [max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.max/).

```
db.subDocs.find()
    .min({"suborders.last_modified":ISODate("2016-09-15T00:00:00Z")})
    .max({"suborders.last_modified":ISODate("2016-09-16T00:00:00Z")})
```

Which returned the same documents as `$elemMatch` but used both bounds on the index.  It ran in 0.021s versus 2-4s for elemMatch and the original find.